# EOF and BOF in ASP

Tags: java, asp-classic, ado

I'm converting an ASP Page to JAVA/JSP

I think I have an understanding of .MoveNext but, I'm not sure what .EOF and .BOF are doing.

Can anyone Help me understand what this ASP code is doing?

**rsVerifyBase.MoveNext**
(I believe this is just moving to the next line, But I'm not sure)

**rsVerifyBase.EOF** ?

**rsVerifyBase.BOF** ?

Including sample code so you can see what I'm looking at

Now that I have a better understanding, is it relative to Java?

if so is there something similar in Java?

My connection is using JDBC Driver instead of the original ADODB which is ASP

Sample Code:

```
Do while not rsVerifyBase.EOF and not rsVerifyBase.BOF
                        sS = rsVerifyBase("")
                        sE = rsVerifyBase("")
                        if (rsVerifyBase("") > cdate(dateString)) AND (InStr(sStart,sS)=0) then%>
                            <tr><td>The <%=rsVerifyBase("")%> currency is not valid until <%=rsVerifyBase("Start_Date")%>.</td></tr>
                        <%  sStart = sStart & sS
                        end if
                        if (rsVerifyBase("") < cdate(dateString)) AND (InStr(sEnd,sE)=0) then%>
                            <tr><td>The <%=rsVerifyBase("")%> currency is not valid after <%=rsVerifyBase("End_Date")%>.</td></tr>
                        <% sEnd = sEnd & sE
                        end if
                        rsVerifyBase.MoveNext
                    loop
```

Comment: It basically reads the RecordSet until it reaches the end.

Comment: `EOF` = end of file.  `BOF` = beginning of file.  Pretty self explanatory.

Comment: What @HanletEscaño said except in this case, it's an ADO [Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510.aspx), not a file.

Comment: A ResultSet in JSP is similar to a Recordset in Classic ASP

Answer (score 2):

That's just an enumeration of the rows of an ADO [`Recordset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510.aspx). It was necessary to make sure you didn't run off the end.

I don't know why the check for BOF since the enumeration is forward-only here.